# react-redux: should I maintain store data redundant?

Tags: reactjs, redux

For example, I have an entity at the backend called jobs, frontend called different ajax to get data by different search filter such as "jobStatus = Canceled" etc...
So should I maintain only one jobList in store? or maintain a couple of list match different ajax?
Thank you for help.

Comment: No, with some exceptions. Rarely you need to save some redundant data because of performance.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to treat your redux store as if it is a database. Normalize your nested lists, store each entity only once and reference it by id in all other places. A good way to do this is to use the Normalizr library. https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

from the redux official docs:

> the recommended approach to managing relational or nested data in a
>   Redux store is to treat a portion of your store as if it were a
>   database, and keep that data in a normalized form

reasons:

> When a piece of data is duplicated in several places, it becomes
>   harder to make sure that it is updated appropriately.
>
> Nested data
>   means that the corresponding reducer logic has to be more nested or
>   more complex. In particular, trying to update a deeply nested field
>   can become very ugly very fast.
>
> Since immutable data updates require
>   all ancestors in the state tree to be copied and updated as well, and
>   new object references will cause connected UI components to re-render,
>   an update to a deeply nested data object could force totally unrelated
>   UI components to re-render even if the data they're displaying hasn't
>   actually changed.

Reference:  http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer~ If I follow this way, it looks like doing some filter work twice because I have to add selector to my container, but I have already done this in backend.